# JavaScript. How to check if a random URL contain values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
const location = ['Bradenton', 'Broward', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Palm Beach'];
var url = '?_dFR[location_page][0]=Miami&_dFR[location_page][1]=Orlando&_dFR[make][0]=Acura&_dFR[make][1]=Audi&_dFR[make][2]=BMW&_dFR';
```

As you see `url` have Miami and Orlando that have in `location`.

The result should be: ['Miami', 'Orlando']. I tried to use regex but it is too complex. Is there an easier way?

Comment: `const contains = location.some(v => url.includes(v))`

Comment: `const contains = location.filter(loc => url.includes(loc))`

Comment: `some` only returns true/false value, but he's looking for a list of results though @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @NickVu Then use `filter()` instead.

Comment: by the way, I've rarely seen Vietnamese on Stackoverflow these days, welcome Minh to the community! :D

Comment: Thank everyone for your answers. Hi Vu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const locations = ['Bradenton', 'Broward', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Palm Beach'];
var url = '?_dFR[location_page][0]=Miami&_dFR[location_page][1]=Orlando&_dFR[make][0]=Acura&_dFR[make][1]=Audi&_dFR[make][2]=BMW&_dFR';

const foundLocs=locations.filter(l=>url.includes(l))

console.log(foundLocs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const locationList = ['Bradenton', 'Broward', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Palm Beach'];
const url = '?_dFR[location_page][0]=Miami&_dFR[location_page][1]=Orlando&_dFR[make][0]=Acura&_dFR[make][1]=Audi&_dFR[make][2]=BMW&_dFR';

const results = locationList.filter(currentLocation => url.includes(currentLocation));

console.log(results);
```

You also can use `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` to ignore case sensitive for your matches

```js
const locationList = ['Bradenton', 'Broward', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Palm Beach'];
//lowercase for `orlando` and uppercase for `MIAMI`
const url = '?_dFR[location_page][0]=MIAMI&_dFR[location_page][1]=orlando&_dFR[make][0]=Acura&_dFR[make][1]=Audi&_dFR[make][2]=BMW&_dFR';

const results = locationList.filter(currentLocation => (url.includes(currentLocation.toLowerCase()) || url.includes(currentLocation) ||  url.includes(currentLocation.toUpperCase())));

console.log(results);
```

Regex version

```js
const locationList = ['Bradenton', 'Broward', 'Miami', 'Orlando', 'Palm Beach'];
//lowercase for `orlando` and uppercase for `MIAMI`
const url = '?_dFR[location_page][0]=MIAMI&_dFR[location_page][1]=orlando&_dFR[make][0]=Acura&_dFR[make][1]=Audi&_dFR[make][2]=BMW&_dFR';

const results = locationList.filter(currentLocation => new RegExp(currentLocation, 'i').exec(url));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This answer is more than I needed. Nice to know there is more way to do this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @Minh!~ Both of us are Vietnamese, I'm glad that we're learning here together :D